# Exponential Graph Animation P5js Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I am trying to animate a growing exponential graph using P5js. 
I have successfully plotted the graph itself, but the "rulers/scales" on the sides won't work.
I want the "window" to scale according to the X and Y axis, just like this example: [Animation](https://www.wtfskins.com/crash) **I am trying to replicate this animation**

I want the graph to "grow" and the rulers/scales on the sides to represent the growth, X is time and Y the multiplier (big text in the middle). As seen on the animation I linked, X and Y values move towards the origin after the graph has gone outside the box.

Link to P5 editor with code: [P5 web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/JonasTheCuriousDev/sketches/BXThmEHN2)

Comment: Please try to explain what you want to achieve in the text. It's at least time consuming to stare at some animations.

Comment: Question edited. I am trying to replicate the animation from the link I included.

Comment: I looked at it once, but when I tried for a the next few times I didn't see anything because the animation stopped. As I got it right now, the scale ticks start to move towards the origin of the coordinate system. But I have not the time to observe this page to get all the details. ***I am trying to replicate this animation*** doesn't explain anything.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear, I want the scale ticks to act just like the scale ticks on the link, Want them to have the right value and move towards the origin. X to represent time and Y to represent the Multiplier value (Y value). As of now the X scale accelerates after a while for some reason and the Y value is going the wrong way.

Comment: I'd say you should also see what ticks are visible. As I see in your code, the X ticks get more and more. As I remember the ticks in the linked animation thin out? But, as I told, it's hard to observe. I'd guess you would be happy with around 5 ticks on each of the coordinate axes, so while the graph grows (and you scale it down), the ticks must change from say, 1,2,3,4,5 to 2,4,6 or the like ...

Comment: That is very much correct! And yes, the ticks thin out as you say

Comment: Another point to do with your code. Start at an x value near to the starting width and decrease the frame rate, so it's easier to concentrate on the interesting part.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one big error in

```js
scaleLevel -= 0.1;
```

because this way it gets zero and you will divide by it within `REscale`.

Your intention is to draw some exponential function `f(x)` in the interval `0` to `x`. The value of `x` is increasing by time. The value of the exponential function is also rising but with another rate. So you will have to use two separate scale factors: `sX = display_width / x` and `sY = display_hight / f(x)`.

I hope this gets you started somehow.
Here is some code to illustrate which way to go:

```js
var x = 10

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function my_func(x) {
  return exp(x * 0.2);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  stroke(155);
  strokeWeight(8);
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  let nPoints = 20;
  let dx = x / nPoints;
  let ymax = my_func(x);
  let dy = ymax / nPoints;
  for (let i = 0; i <= x; i += dx) {
    xValue = map(i, 0, x, 0, width);
    yValue = map(my_func(i), 0, ymax, height, 0);
    vertex(xValue, yValue);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

I omitted the ticks on the axes. I decided to create a static plot for the value of `x` in the between 0 and 10. The code can easily be changed into an animation by removing the `noLoop();` statement in the `setup` function and adding the line `x += somedelta;` within the `draw` function.

Comment: Cool! Will have a look. Just a question, did you manage to get the Y ticks to move towards origin and have the right values?

Comment: @Jonas Did you have a look meanwhile? Regarding the ticks, please read [label coordinate axis with 1-2-5-ticks for given numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61502601/2932052) :-)

Comment: Good idea to put `const` in front of `xValue` so it's not attached to the window.