# label coordinate axis with 1-2-5-ticks for given numeric range

Tags: algorithm, plot, language-agnostic, axis-labels

The somewhat unclear question [Exponential Graph Animation P5js Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61476555/2932052) contains 
an interesting detail about programmatically labeling axes for a broad variety of ranges. 
I instantly remembered that [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/) does what I searched for.
By interactively zooming in the preview window 
(and without any [particular ticks specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23155048/2932052)),
I observed that it automatically selects a labeling scheme with an amount of between 4 and 10 ticks and a fixed distance of 1, 2, or 5 times some power of 10.

The following 4 examples can be taken as snapshots of this interactive process.

```
gnuplot> set xrange [0:1]
gnuplot> set yrange [0:exp(1)]
gnuplot> plot exp(x)
```

[image: exp(x) function in xrange 0..1]

```
gnuplot> set xrange [0:2]
gnuplot> set yrange [0:exp(2)]
gnuplot> plot exp(x)
```

[image: exp(x) function in xrange 0..2]

```
gnuplot> set yrange [0:exp(5)]
gnuplot> set xrange [0:5]
gnuplot> plot exp(x)
```

[image: exp(x) function in xrange 0..5]

```
gnuplot> set yrange [0:exp(10)]
gnuplot> set xrange [0:10]
gnuplot> plot exp(x)
```

[image: exp(x) function in xrange 0..10]

To implement such a labeling scheme, 
**how do I find the ideal 1-2-5-tick distance for a given range?** 
(in pseudo code or some usual language like JavaScript or Python)

Answer (score 0):

To get one of these 1-2-5-tick schemes from a `range` (`0..max`), we have to separate order of magnitude (`exponent`) and digits (`mantissa`), and to find the most appropriate digit (1, 2, or 5) below or equal to the most significant digit of a `representative`.

See such a function in JavaScript:

```js
// find 1-2-5-tick distance for a given range
function tick_distance(range) {
  let find_factor = function(v) {
    if (v >= 5) {
      v = 5;
    } else if (v >= 2) {
      v = 2;
    } else if (v >= 1) {
      v = 1;
    }
    return v;
  };

  let representative = range * 0.24
  let l10 = Math.log10(representative);
  let exponent = Math.floor(l10);
  let mantissa = l10-exponent;
  let realdist = Math.pow(10, mantissa);
  let factor = find_factor(realdist);
  let dist = factor * Math.pow(10, exponent);
  return dist;
}
```

The heuristic factor of `0.24` for the `representative` gives tick counts between 4 and 10 over changing orders of magnitude; `0.23` would also work whereas `0.25` provides the maximum of 10 ticks only for ranges of `2*10^n`.

- `0.22` gives sometimes 11 ticks
- `2.26` gives sometimes 3 ticks

I admit that I'm myself am interested in the "exact value" for this factor.